# Autoencoder with Keras: How to get better results?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, autoencoder

I have a collection of [1000 images](https://www.file-upload.net/download-14195987/images.zip.html) which are very similar but not identical. Here are three examples:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvjtW.jpg) [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaOl2.jpg) [Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/465TI.jpg)

Now my goal is to create a good working autoencoder for these images.

I tried to create an autoencoder with Keras. The results were okay. But I would like to know what I can improve here.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

BATCH_SIZE = 50; EPOCHS = 10
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_batches = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('cropped_64/',
        target_size=(64,64), shuffle=True, class_mode='input', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# ENCODER
input_img = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(192, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
encoded = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

# LATENT SPACE
latentSize = (8,8,32)

# DECODER
direct_input = Input(shape=latentSize)
x = Conv2D(192, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')(direct_input)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(192, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(48, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

# COMPILE
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
decoder = Model(direct_input, decoded)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoder(encoded))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=30)
model_filepath = 'model1.keras'
save_best = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_filepath, monitor='loss', save_best_only=True, mode='min')

history = autoencoder.fit_generator(train_batches,
        steps_per_epoch = train_batches.samples // BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs = EPOCHS, verbose=2, callbacks=[es, save_best])


Epoch 1/10
20/20 - 88s - loss: 0.5457
Epoch 2/10
20/20 - 87s - loss: 0.5226
Epoch 3/10
20/20 - 88s - loss: 0.5009
Epoch 4/10
20/20 - 91s - loss: 0.4481
Epoch 5/10
20/20 - 89s - loss: 0.4368
Epoch 6/10
20/20 - 90s - loss: 0.3707
Epoch 7/10
20/20 - 85s - loss: 0.3186
Epoch 8/10
20/20 - 68s - loss: 0.3083
Epoch 9/10
20/20 - 65s - loss: 0.3048
Epoch 10/10
20/20 - 69s - loss: 0.3028
```

Comment: Are you trying to improve your autoencoder's accuracy or precision, or both?

Comment: Can you explain me the difference between both? I just want to use the autoencoder for reconstruction, not for classification.

Comment: Accuracy is how well your autoencoder can differentiate between items it is presented, while Precision is how often your autoencoder can detect items.